# How to change which plot is on top in sns using Python

Tags: python, seaborn

Is it possible to change the order in which of the plot is on top of a sns relplot graph?

---

We have a graph with three different plots, where the plot in green (*outside_temperature*) is blocking the sight of the other two plots (*temp_20* and *temp_60*).

[image]

The order we want is to let *temp_60* be in front, *temp_20* as mid and *outside_temperature* to be the plot farthest behind.

**Code used to generate the Graph:**

```
def create_lineplot(sensor1, sensor2):

    months = mdates.MonthLocator()  # every month
    years_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m')  # This is a format. Will be clear in Screenshot

    # Filtering data to only select relevant columns and data from the year 2020
    sensor1_copy = sensor1[['dev_id', 'temp_20', 'temp_60', 'datetime']].copy()
    sensor1_copy["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(sensor1_copy["datetime"])
    sens1 = sensor1_copy[sensor1_copy['datetime'].dt.year == 2020]

    # Filtering data to only select relevant columns and data from the year 2020
    sensor2_copy = sensor2[['dev_id', 'outside_temperature', 'datetime']].copy()
    sensor2_copy["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(sensor2_copy["datetime"])
    sens2 = sensor2_copy[sensor2_copy['datetime'].dt.year == 2020]

    cdf = pd.concat([sens1, sens2])
    mdf = pd.melt(cdf, id_vars=['datetime', 'dev_id'], var_name=['Temperature'])
    mdf.rename(columns={"value": "Temperature in Celsius C", "datetime": "Datetime"}, inplace = True)

    print(mdf)

    g = sns.relplot(data=mdf, x='Datetime', y='Temperature in Celsius C', kind='line', hue='Temperature', height=5, aspect=3)

    g._legend.remove()

    axes = g.axes.flat[0]

    axes.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)
    axes.xaxis.set_major_formatter(years_fmt)
    axes.xaxis.set_minor_locator(months)

    plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.legend(loc='upper right')

    plt.savefig('lineplot.png')

    plt.show()
```

**An example of the Data (*print(mdf)*):**

```
Datetime               dev_id          Temperature            Temperature in Celsius C
2020-02-04 16:32:21    sensor1         temp_20                4.52
2020-02-04 17:32:25    sensor1         temp_20                4.48
...                    ...             ...                    ...
2020-02-13 02:45:45    sensor1         temp_60                2.34
2020-02-13 03:45:49    sensor1         temp_60                2.32
...                    ...             ...                    ...
2020-03-13 20:39:54    sensor2         outside_temperature    6.00
2020-03-13 20:49:53    sensor2         outside_temperature    6.50
```

---

**After changing the order of the hue:**

```
g = sns.relplot(data=mdf, x='Datetime', y='Temperature in Celsius C', kind='line', hue='Temperature', hue_order=['outside_temperature', 'temp_20', 'temp_60'], height=5, aspect=3)
```

[image]

Also, this is how the plots temp_20 and temp_60 looks, when outside_temperature is not added to the graph:

[image]

Comment: Probably the curves are drawn in the order of the hue.  So, `hue_order=['outside_temperature', 'temp_20', 'temp_0']` should set the desired drawing order.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, @JohanC. The order is in fact changed, but no difference in the plot. I have added a new image of the graph to the question, so you can see

Comment: Since outside temperature appears to be much more dominant in the graph, you might try using a lighter color for that series. There might be an alpha argument or a different color you could employ that would allow the other two series to show up more effectively.